# Variable binding techniques used in proof assistants?

Tags: implementation, binders

There are many resources ([1](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/%7Eplclub/poplmark/), [2](https://jesper.sikanda.be/posts/1001-syntax-representations.html), [3](https://blog.jez.io/variables-and-binding/), [4](https://eelcovisser.org/blog/writing/2015/01/30/a-theory-of-name-resolution/)) to learn about various techniques for manipulating syntax with variable binding, however, I haven't seen many descriptions of which specific techniques are actually used in existing proof assistants. Is there some existing chart for this kind of information, or is it "folklore"?

Comment: @GuyCoder The linked answer has an accepted answer now.